# ¿En MySQL es posible guardar en el mismo campo o columna una fecha y dos horas?

Tags: mysql

Esta es una pregunta de esas que te vienen cuando estás respondiendo a situaciones planteadas aquí en Stackoverflow.

**¿Existe la posibilidad en MySQL de guardar en un mismo campo una fecha y dos horas diferentes?**

O sea, si tengo esto:

```
Fecha inicio: 2017-09-04
Hora  inicio: 15:30:00
Hora  fin   : 18:30:00
```

¿Podría guardar todo eso en un solo campo?

De poder hacerlo, ¿sería factible?

En una posible solución evitaría soluciones rebuscadas. Mi pregunta va referida a la posibilidad de un **tipo de dato** que permita eso y que **los datos almacenados sean lo que son**, o sea, fechas y/o horas.

Comment: separado por comas, claro...pero es una mala idea a nivel diseño. No hay un tipo de datos que te permita esto. Por definición, los tipos de datos son atómicos. En este caso, lo mejor serían dos columnas

Comment: no en un mismo campo. el campo es de tipo date, o sea tiene una sola fecha.. salvo que lo definieras como por ejemplo varchar y te encargaras de la logica vos mismo.

Comment: Como Varchar creo que se podria, pero sera mas dificil manejar eso, lo mejor seria guardar la fecha y la primera hora en un datetime, y en otro campo guardar solo la hora, asi seria mas facil de operar pienso.

Comment: En tren de proponer soluciones raras, si solo necesitas horas y minutos y el campo quieres que sea un `datetime` podrías usar los milisegundos para guardar los minutos adicionales de la `Hora  fin` con respecto a `Hora  inicio`

Comment: En realidad la pregunta iba en el sentido de si existía un tipo de dato que permitiese eso, o hacerlo manualmente, pero sin manipulaciones muy rebuscadas y/o peligrosas. No me gusta otorgar tipos de datos extraños a la definición normal que debe tener una columna, ya que eso trae complicaciones por ejemplo a la hora de hacer cálculos, o es más fácil cometer errores de digitación que serían difíciles de detectar.

Comment: @A.Cedano No hay un tipo de datos que te permita hacer eso de forma directa, sin tener que manipular su contenido

Comment: Agradecería una respuesta @Lamak acompañada de documentación, para que no sea un simple **no**. Quizá indicando la posibilidad que dan los campos de tipo fecha/hora. Como orientación, lo había pensado y se ha comentado por aquí, se puede usar dos columnas en vez de tres, en la primera se colocan la fecha y la hora de inicio y en la segunda la hora de fin. Supongo que tampoco habrá la posibilidad de almacenar dos horas en un solo campo que sea del tipo adecuado.

Comment: ¿Alguna versión en particular de MySQL?

Comment: Preferiblemente una versión actualizada @AlvaroMontoro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En MySQL no existe un tipo de dato que sea "rango de fechas", que es lo que parece que estarías buscando. En la documentación de MySQL puedes encontrar los [tipos de datos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) y los [tipos específicos para fecha/hora](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) que son:

- `DATE`
- `TIME`
- `DATETIME`
- `TIMESTAMP`
- `YEAR`

Que serían todos valores unitarios y no múltiples (que es lo que necesitarías). En otros motores de base de datos podrías definir tu propio tipo para lo que buscas, pero MySQL no cuenta con esa funcionalidad.

...aunque quizás podrías simularla utilizando un VARCHAR (aunque requeriría que aplicaras funciones sobre el campo por lo que no es muy natural o simple) o un objeto de tipo JSON ([disponible a partir de MySQL 5.7.8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)).

MySQL 5.7: La idea sería que guardaras un JSON con fecha, hora de inicio y hora de fin, y luego accedieras a los valores para poder operar sobre ellos (no haría falta tener funciones especiales o *castear* valores).

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo ([lo puedes ejecutar aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hrMheUJvTimUxty8pLFNL7/0)):

```
CREATE TABLE pruebafechas (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(100),
    valor JSON,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO pruebafechas(nombre, valor) 
VALUES      ('cita con doctor', '{ "fecha": "2017-09-05", "inicio": "08:00:00", "fin": "10:00:00" }'),
            ('almuerzo', '{ "fecha": "2017-09-05", "inicio": "11:00:00", "fin": "11:30:00" }');

SELECT nombre
FROM   pruebafechas
WHERE  valor->"$.inicio" = "08:00:00";
-- Devuelve "cita con doctor"

SELECT nombre
FROM   pruebafechas
WHERE  HOUR("11:10:00") BETWEEN valor->"$.inicio" AND valor->"$.fin";
-- Devuelve "almuerzo"
```

Comment: ¡Excelente! Muchísimas gracias.