# Obtener hora mysql

Tags: mysql

Buenas compañeros tengo un pequeño problema, tengo conectado un sensor a mysql el envía datos perfectamente, le tengo un timestamp y lo hace bien, lo que tengo que hacer es crear otra columna donde solo me ponga la hora, HH:MM:SS  solo hora, ya que el timestamp me combina fecha + hora, en mysql creo otra columna,le pongo el tipo Time, pero cuando mi sensor envía un dato el tiempo lo pone en 00:00:00, en cambio el timestamp lo hace correcto,  les agradecería me ayudaran.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor. Tambien usa signos de separación que si no la pregunta no se entiende casi.

Comment: La pregunta no es del todo clara. No obstante, debes saber que si declaras una columna como [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) estarás almacenando en ella la fecha y la hora. Luego, si las quieres por separado puedes hacerlo al momento de la consulta. Tener una segunda columna sería innecesario y redundante.

Comment: prueba guardando como texto para ver que esta llegando si la información que estas queriendo guardar es correcta

Comment: Mira incluso [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/99795/29967), en la que yo mismo buscaba la posibilidad de un tipo de campo que me guardase una fecha e intervalos de horas, o sea, un campo con tres datos distintos. Es que, mientras menos redundancia, mejor.

Comment: no se cual es el problema que guarde la fecha y hora si quieres comparar con otra hora tendras que tener en cuenta el dia , puedes tener la hora de esta forma  `Select TIME(tu_campo) from tu_tabla`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un tipo de columna que se llama TIME. Sólo podrás guardar la hora.

**Ejemplo** crear tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE tests (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    start_at TIME,
    end_at TIME
);
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO tests(name,start_at,end_at)
VALUES('Test 1', '08:00:00','10:00:00');
```

Select:

```
SELECT 
    name, start_at, end_at
FROM
    tests;
```

[Fuente](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-time/)

Answer (score 1):

En mysql, la inicialización automática con CURRENT_TIMESTAMP sólo funciona con los tipos TIMESTAMP y DATETIME. 
Para el tipo TIME, a menos que uses un trigger -el cual puede ser costoso para algo tan simple- deberás asignar el valor inicial desde el INSERT: `time(now())`. Aunque casualmente, podrías usar la misma función en el SELECT sin necesidad de agregar otra columna.