# Implementación de un campo datetime-range con MySQL-Django?

Tags: mysql, python, django

Necesito crear dos campos nuevos que van a almacenar `fechas` de vigencia
`(2010-10-01,2018-10-01)`, cómo por ejemplo vigencia de una licencia de conducción

Se que existe este campo con [PosgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/), [DateTimeRangeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/).
Pero mi modelo esta con [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/).

Entonces quiero saber si han hecho algo parecido, y cuál es la mejor forma. Obviamente he pensado en guardar los datos por separado:

```
class Cotizacion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_inicio  = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    fecha_final  = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

Pero creo que no es la mejor solución.

Gracias.

Comment: Esta pregunta invita a los usuarios a emitir una opinión, lo que no debería ocurrir (consulta la guía _[ask]_). Si tienes una pregunta específica con tu implementación, agrega un __[mcve]__ que ilustre este problema.

Comment: Si sólo quieres la fecha y no la precisión de tiempo puedes usar el método DateField en Django y sólo guardará la fecha. Más allá de eso, no hay mejor solución a menos que quieras parsear un string cada vez que retires el dato de la base de datos (No es recomendado).

Comment: No, Estoy buscando la mejor forma de implementarlo, simplemente pongo la forma mas fácil de hacerlo, para evitar que me digan eso.

Comment: Mira esta otra pregunta como referencia: [¿En MySQL es posible guardar en el mismo campo o columna una fecha y dos horas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/99795/250). (Sé que en ésta hablamos de dos fechas y en la otra de dos horas, pero la idea es más o menos la misma).